# Java array replacements

Tags: java, arrays, replace, integer, iteration

Hello I have 3 integer arrays.

- array #1 has information and contains duplicates.
- array #2 contains values that might be in array 1.
- array #3 has replacement values.
- array #2 and array #3 are the same size and do not contain duplicates.

I want to check if an element from array #2 is in array #1.
If the element is in array #1 I want it replaced with an element from array #3.
The element from #3 that replaces the original needs to have the same location in the array as #2.
A way I could do it is:

```
for (int i = 0; i<arr1.length; i++){
  for (int a = 0; a<arr2.length; a++){
    if(arr1[i]==arr2[a]){
      arr1[i]=arr3[a];
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

What I am wondering is if there is a quicker or better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current algorithm has time complexity `O(n * m)` with `n` = length of array #1 and `m` = length of array #2.

There is an algorithm that has a better time complexity.

Sketch of algorithm:

1. Sort array #1, keep track of how elements move to reverse sorting at the end (`O(n log(n))`)
2. Sort array #2, permutate elements in array #3 accordingly (`O(m log(m))`)
3. Find all elements in array #1, that are also in array #2 and replace them with the elements at same position in array #3 (`O(n + m)`)
4. Un-Sort array #1 utilizing the tracking from 1. (`O(n)`)

In total, we get `O(n log(n) + m log(m) + n + m + n) ∈ O(n log(n) + m log(m))`

If arrays #2 and #3 must be un-shuffled aswell, one can either copy those arrays or keep track during sorting aswell and un-shuffle them aswell since un-shuffling takes "only" `O(m)`.

Comment: Sorting is not required. Overall complexity of O(n + m) is possible: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63606579/256196) for how to do it with one pass each over arrays 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Set` of the elements in array1 to determine if an element is in it.
Loop over array2 and copy over forom array3 if the set contains its element:

```
Set<T> set = Arrays.stream(arr1).collect(toSet()); // O(n)
for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++){         // O(m)
    if (set.contains(arr2[i])) {
      arr2[i] = arr3[i];
    }
}
```

Given array1 is size n and array2 is size m...
All operations on a Set are constant time (ie O(1)), so building the set cost O(n).
Looping over array2 is O(m) - the set lookup cost is O(1)

Overall cost O(n + m) - ie "linear".

Your current cost is O(n * m) - ie "quadratic".

---

Note: You have not specified the type of the arrays.  If they are primitive (eg `int`), building the set needs the minor enhancement of adding a call to `boxed()`, because java does not support collections of primitives:

```
Arrays.stream(arr1).boxed().collect(toSet())
```

Comment: OP says `3 integer arrays`. You should use `Arrays.stream(arr1)` instead of `Arrays.stream()`.

Comment: @saka1029 thank you for spotting the typo. All fixed 

Comment: It seems I may have been a bit unclear. I want the values from array #3 copied into array #1. Your method doesn't appear to give back the location of the element in array #1. I hoped the example code would make it more clear what I was trying to do.

Comment: You may want to specify the type of `Set` used by using `Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new);`. Otherwise, no guarantees are made on the type of `Set` returned and set construction, as well as `contains(...)` may not run in linear/constant time.

Comment: @Turing85 `toSet()` always returns a `HashSet` - read the source code for yourself. If you think about it, there is no other sensible choice. Although *technically* you are correct about there being no guarantee according to the method contract, as a matter of practicality it will *always* return a `HashSet`.

Comment: @Bohemian I prefer sticking to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet()), especially if it explicitly mentions that "*There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the Set returned; if more control over the returned Set is required, use [`toCollection(Supplier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toCollection(java.util.function.Supplier)).*"

Answer (score 0):

Array #2 and Array #3 are a bad replacement for a HashMap.

```
Map<T, T> replacements = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
  replacements.put(arr2[i], arr3[i]);
}
for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  if (replacements.containsKey(arr1[i]) {
    arr1[i] = replacements.get(arr1[i]);
  }
}
```

This will have approximately O(n) time complexity.